# Is it possible to find/get all audio ports from an Usb attached device in Android?

Tags: java, android, audio, usb, android-audiomanager

I'm developing a streaming music application. I connected via Usb a MIDI-controller that have 2 audio ports (2 x Jack 3.5mm): one for speakers and one for headphones.
I established the connection and communication with controller.
Android automatically detect the audio port for speakers as default.
When I plugg in some speakers or headphones in the speakers port(default), the apps runs well and the music is heard.
When I plugg in the second port some headphones, the music isn't heard.

I used **getDevice()** method from **AudioManager** when my controller was connected to my Samsung Galaxy Tab S8 and it has 3 devices: **first is Type 2(AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_BUILTIN_SPEAKER)**, **second is Type 11(AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_USB_DEVICE)** and the **third Type 18(AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_TELEPHONY)**. After connection, the selected device is Type 11 and the music is heard in the master port(automatically default selected by Android).

I checked with this function to see if something happen when I plug the headphones in their port(second port) but nothing. I mention that I put the permission in the mafinest:

`<uses-permissionandroid:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />`:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        AudioDeviceInfo[] audioDevices = audioManager.getDevices(AudioManager.GET_DEVICES_OUTPUTS);
        for(AudioDeviceInfo deviceInfo : audioDevices){
            if(deviceInfo.getType()==AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_WIRED_HEADPHONES){
                Log.d(TAG, "AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_WIRED_HEADPHONES");
            } else if(deviceInfo.getType()==AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_WIRED_HEADSET) {
                Log.d(TAG, "AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_WIRED_HEADSET");
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "something else - " + deviceInfo.getType());
            }
        }
```

I think that Android automatically detect first audio port as default because I found this in logcat:
**info::    I/AudioPathManager: loadAudioPath() : loaded audio path is usb (6)**

**My questions are**:

How can I detect when the headphones are plugged in the second jack port?

Does exist a library that could help me?

Is it possible to find/get all audio ports from an Usb attached device to redirect the audio output in these 2 ports simultaneously?

Comment: 1. Can you play music on that second port from a PC for example? 2. Are you sure that second port is for a speaker and not for a microphone? 3. Which MIDI controller exactly are you using (brand & model)?

Comment: @zomega I'm using a Dj Control Starlight from Hercules and, yes, playing in a software on PC the headphones port works well